# How to compare two dataframes and find the combination for which there is value in first dataframe but not in second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes with same columns say name, jan, feb, march, april. I want to compare the two dataframes and find out the name, month combination for which I have value in my first dataframe but not in my second dataframe.

df1:

| Name | jan | feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 125 | 225 | NaN |
| DEF | NaN | 30 | 214 |

df2:

| Name | jan | feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 125 | NaN | NaN |
| XYZ | 254 | 130 | NaN |

Expected output:

| Name | Month |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | feb |
| Def | feb |
| Def | March |

I tried to merge the two dataframes, but it is not giving me the expected result. I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` to "Name" + `stack` + `reset_index` the DataFrames and outer `merge` on name and month. Then filter the merged DataFrame by the condition:

```
out = df1.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index().merge(df2.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(), on=['Name','level_1'], how='outer')
out = out.loc[out['0_x'].notna() & out['0_y'].isna(), ['Name','level_1']].rename(columns={'level_1':'Month'})
```

Output:

```
  Name  Month
1  ABC    feb
2  DEF    feb
3  DEF  March
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you used the loc function to filter the merged dataframe? if our condition is satisfied, out.loc[true, ['name', 'level_1']] - how does this work?

Comment: @Minato `out['0_x'].notna() & out['0_y'].isna()` creates a boolean mask. We want to identify the cells in `df1` that have non-NaN values but the corresponding cell in `df2` has, right? So since "_x" suffix from `df1` and "_y" is from `df2`, ``out['0_x'].notna()` is evaluating if the values that came from `df1` is not-NaN or not.  `out['0_y'].isna()` is doing the opposite evaluation for the part that was merged from `df2`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach:

```
# only if not already index
# df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
# df2 = df2.set_index('Name')

s = ((df1.notna()&df1.ne(df2.reindex_like(df1)))
     .rename_axis('Month', axis=1).stack())
s[s].reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Name  Month
0  ABC     feb
1  DEF     feb
2  DEF   March
```